Discord bot setup issue with Python: Missing Privileged Intents error
So, I found some old code from python (discord library), using python/discord/sqlite3. I tried to run it, but it returns me an error, when checking the token. I spent 4 hours debugging it, but I still don't know why it does not work:
The code when run throws an error here:
File "C:\Users\HARDPC\Downloads\AIBOT\very_very_cool_code\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    bot.run('TOKEN')

This is my code for the bot, the error "Missing Privileged Intents" occurs in the commented last line:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import sqlite3

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.command(name='get-users')
async def get_users(ctx):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE age >?", (25,))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        await ctx.send(f'ID: {row[0]}, Name: {row[1]}, Age: {row[2]}')

bot.run('TOKEN') # <= Returns me error (I have a token from the Discord developer portal)

So could you help me, please?

old code can be wrong. You have to search newer code or you have to check documentation if functions needs changes.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

if you have Missing Privileged Intents then maybe you have to login to discord developer portal and change settings for your applications.

I run your code and it shows me error
Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may no

I used Google to search Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may no
and it gives me link to other question:
python - Discord.py error message: discord.ext.commands.bot: Privileged message content intent is missing - Stack Overflow
and there is information that it needs
intents.message_content = True

Now code works on my computer.
Problem resolved (with Google) in 1 minute.

EDIT:
It may need also to visit discord developer portal and change settings for your applications - you have to set correct privileges.

It still returns errror

you didn't show FULL error message - maybe you have problem with different privilege. Besides it may need to visit discord developer portal and change settings for your applications - you have to set correct privileges on portal.
